# Compute x/y without Arithmetical Operators

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am going through the "Elements of Programming Interview" in python currently and have gotten stuck at this part. The code below is simply multiplies two numbers without using any operators; the explanation given by the authors is below:

> We can compute the largest k such that (2^k)y <= x, subtract (2^k)y
>   from x, and add 2^k to the quotient.  For example is x = (1011) and y
>   =(10), then k = 2, since 2 x 2^2 <= 11 and 2 x 2^3 > 11.  We subtract (1000) form (1011) to get (11), add 2^k = 2^2 = (100) to the quotient,
>   and continue by updating x to (11).
>
> A better way to find the largest k in each iteration is to recognize
>   that it keeps decreasing.  Therefore, instead of testing in each
>   iteration whether (2^0)y, (2^1)y, (2^2)y, ... is less than or equal to
>   x, after we initially find the largest k such that (2^k)y <= x, in
>   subsequent iteration we test   (2^k-1)y, (2^k-2)y, (2^k-3)y, ... with
>   x.    For the example given earlier, after setting the quoient to
>   (100) we continue with (11).  Now the laegest k such that (2^k)y <=
>   (11) is 0, so we add 2^0 = (1) to the quotient, which is now (101). 
>   We continue with (11) - (10) = (1), Since (1)

```
def divide(x, y):

    result, power = 0, 32
    y_power = y << power

    while x >= y:

        while y_power > x:

            y_power >>= 1
            power -= 1

        result += 1 << power
        x -= y_power

    return result
```

My Questions are:

1. How is the algorithm working (overview)
2. whey does power = 32
3. why are we shifting y by power (32)
4. what does y_power represent
5. why are we adding 1 << power to result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is long division for binary numbers. You probably learned this for decimal numbers in school.

If we want to divide `x` by `y` we ask our self "how many times does `y` fit into `x` if we add as many zeros to it as possible?". Adding n zeros to `y` is equivalent to multiplying with 2^n or shifting left by n.

```
power = 32
y_power = y << power
```

The first guess of the algorithm is to add 32 zeros to `y`, which is shifting it left with `power`. So, if you know your result might be >= 2^33, you would have to use a larger initial value for `power`.

```
while y_power > x:
   y_power >>= 1
   power -= 1
```

In the inner loop it will test if `y_power` already fits into `x` and if not, will "move it one digit to the right".

```
result += 1 << power
```

When this is done, it will just write the "number of how many times y shifted left fits into x" to the result. As in binary numbers this can just be zero or one and the inner loop skipped all zeros, this must be one.

```
x -= y_power
```

As you know from long division, we now need to subtract this multiple of the divisor, `y`, from the dividend and continue with the result.

```
while x >= y:
```

We will stop if this difference, `y`, is smaller than `x` and it is therefore impossible for 2^power * `y` to fit into `x`.

**Example**
Let's calculate 15/5:

```
 1111 / 101 = 11
-1010
------
  101
 -101
------
    0
```

We have `x`=1111 and `y`=101 and start with with `power=1` for brevity. First we calculate `y_power = y<<power = 101<<1 = 1010`. As `1010 > 1111` is false we skip the inner loop and add `1<<power = 1<<1 = 10` to the result. Then we subtract `y_power = 1010` from `x = 1111` and get `101`. Now `y_power = 1010 > 101 = x` is true and we decrement `power`, so we get `power = 0` and `y_power = y<<power = 101`. Now `y_power>x`is false again and we add `1<<power = 1` to our result and get `x - y_power = 0`. Now `x >= y` is false and we are finished with `result = 11`.